# How to initialize bar code scanner on App startup

Tags: xamarin.forms, qr-code

I have a requirement for my xamarin cross platform application that as soon as app start up .QR Scanner set in to read the code. on completing scanning a beep will be ring up.and app again ready for next scanning how can i get this done. what i have done is on button click scanner start, its read code, then i have to press button again to start it again.

```
public HomePage()
        {
            Button scanBtn = new Button
            {
                Text = "Scan Barcode",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };

            scanBtn.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var scanResult = await Acr.BarCodes.BarCodes.Instance.Read();
                if (!scanResult.Success)
                {
                    await this.DisplayAlert("Alert ! ", "Sorry ! \n Failed to read the Barcode !", "OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.15.33/SMS/WebServices/SMSService.svc");
                    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
                    {
                        Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
                    };

                    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
                    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
                    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

                    _client = new SMSServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
                    _client.ValidateStudentAsync("123-admin");
                    _client.ValidateStudentCompleted += _client_ValidateStudentCompleted; ;
                    // await this.DisplayAlert("Scan Successful !", String.Format("Barcode Format : {0} \n Barcode Value : {1}", scanResult.Format, scanResult.Code), "OK");
                }
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    scanBtn
                }
            };
        }
```

and in app.cs

```
 public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new HomePage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            MainPage = new HomePage();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            MainPage = new HomePage();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            MainPage = new HomePage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms/) to read QR codes. To initialize this plugin you should call method to init into each project (Android, iOS, UWP) like this:

For Android in MainActivity.cs class call:

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Droid.Platform.Init();
```

For iOS in AppDeletage.cs class call

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
```

And finally to read QR Codes:

```cs
private async void Scan() {
        var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () => {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
            });
        };

        // Navigate to our scanner page
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}
```

Comment: Very nice and accurate. just one step ahead, how to alert through beep, or sound to card holder?any tip in this regards?

Comment: Install the [XamarinAudioManager NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinAudioManager) if it was helpfull pls mark it as an answer.